# Match Column only if it is not empty

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

I want to match column only if it is not empty

```
select *
from users
where message = 'test' AND phone like '%813%'
```

Where condition should be called only if phone column is not null

else below query should be called

```
select * from users where message = 'test'
```

means `AND phone like '%813%'` should be called only if phone is not null

Answer (score 1):

Use `CASE`

```
select *
from users
where message = 'test' AND 
    case when phone is not null 
    then phone like '%813%'
    else 1 end
```

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: @Strawberry it will match phone column only when this column is not null else it will return rows where column is null

Comment: I see. It's just a longwinded way of writing coalesce() - but still; there's no actual comparison there !?! So, it's the same as saying `SELECT * FROM users WHERE message = 'test' AND (phone LIKE '%813%' OR phone IS NULL)` - this seems more intuitive to me.